# Is it possible to have scss file in dist folder of angular library?

Tags: angular, sass, gulp, angular-library

Is it possible to have scss/css file in dist folder without using viewEncapsulation.None and gulp? While building the library I can only see the JS files but I want to import my component specific scss file in global css

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can have css file in dist folder like the following tree. project > dist > assets > css > your css file.

Comment: little explanation would help